# Angular 4 children doesn't work

Tags: angular

I want to click on a link or even simpler type the `/child` in the url and see that page, but for me doesn't work.

I guess I miss something.
In my create html page I have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

In this component create, I have a child search-result component that is on the same level with goods and payment child components.

On the search-result html page I have the links for goods and payment.

```
http://localhost:5050/create/search-result/search-results
```

When I click on goods I want to have the url:

```
http://localhost:5050/create-trade/goods
```

Now doesn't work. Why? Every time I get redirected to login page.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary float-right" routerLink="/goods">
<a class="btn btn-primary float-right" routerLink="/payment">
```

#### Router

```
{path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
{path: 'create/:section', component: CreateTradeComponent, ,
 children: [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'search-results', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'search-results', component: TradeSearchResultsComponent},
  {path: 'goods', component: GoodsComponent},
  {path: 'payment', component: PaymentComponent},
 ]
},
{path: '**', redirectTo: 'login'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to redirect from create component child route. It will produce URL like `/create/search-result/search-results`, as it creates a URL from current activated route. Before creating route you should go route segment route segment back by using `../`. Then you're all set.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary float-right" routerLink="['../goods']">
<a class="btn btn-primary float-right" routerLink="['../payment']">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a router outlet inside the create component. Not inside the  search-result. Place the below code in create component

```
<a [routerLink]="['goods']">goods</a>
<a [routerLink]="['payment']">payment</a>
```

Comment: this is what I said my friend. The router outlet is in create component. The buttons are in the search result component, because from there I have to go on goods and payment.